# Creating a push notification on receiving chat

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am fairly new to angular 2 and Firebase but i managed to create a chat app [here](https://github.com/pujan1/temp) and my end goal is to create a push notification when there is a new message in the chat app.

1. I tried installing [this](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/blob/master/docs/pushNotifications.md) but it is very difficult as i couldn't understand the document.
2. I tried the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example) as well. but the app wont detect the Notification.

Any help on how to approach this right?

this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

 export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  name: any;
  msgVal: string = '';

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
        this.items = af.database.list('/messages', {
          query: {
            limitToLast: 5
          }
        });

        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => { 
          if(auth) {
            this.name = auth;
          }
        });
    }

login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    });
   }

chatSend(theirMessage: string) {
      this.items.push({ message: theirMessage, name: this.name.facebook.displayName});
      this.msgVal = '';
  }

mychange(){
   console.log("change happned"); // updated value
  }
 }
```

and my app.module file contains,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {initializeApp,database} from 'firebase';

export const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyAQUetWt-pH-WuMTZ-lonP2ykICOl4KiPw",
   authDomain: "anguchat-eb370.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://anguchat-eb370.firebaseio.com",
   storageBucket: "anguchat-eb370.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "267732203493"
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot){
  var x = snapshot.val()
  console.log("This prints whenever there is a new message");
});

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You cannot send messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging directly *from* a device *to* another device. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37435750, http://stackoverflow.com/q/37990140 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/38372147.You *can* however use Cloud Functions with Firebase to securely send notifications. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: i am sorry i couldnt explain it right .. 
i am trying to get browser notifications, 
kinda like these http://www.girliemac.com/assets/images/articles/2014/03/notifications.png

Comment: Yes, I got that. And [FCM.js allows you to receive those](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). But you cannot send such notifications directly from one browser to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would subscribe to the messages database in your component. If you want to use [this](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications) for push notifications. You will have to import `PushNotificationsModule` in your module and `PushNotificationsService` in your component.

before the push nofications work, user has to accept [them](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/blob/master/docs/pushNotifications.md#requesting-permission).

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { PushNotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

 export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  name: any;
  msgVal: string = '';

    constructor(
      public af: AngularFire,
      private _pushNotifications: PushNotificationsService) {

        this._pushNotifications.requestPermission(); // requestion permission for push notification

        this.items = af.database.list('/messages', {
          query: {
            limitToLast: 5
          }
        });

        af.database.list('/messages', {
          query: {
            limitToLast: 1
          }
        }).subscribe((messages: Array<any>) => {
          // get the last message from messages array
          this._pushNotifications.create('some title', { body: 'body text' }).subscribe(
            res => {
              // do something
            },
            err => {
              // do something
            }
          );
       });

        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => { 
          if(auth) {
            this.name = auth;
          }
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: btw any idea if this service provides onclick events? 

Like clickking on the notification redirects you to the desired place

Comment: I do not know, I have never used that package before.